# Iterate through 2 generators in python while comparing each item value

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to compare 2 generators of huge data (sorted - I am reading the data using SQL query) to find elements present in one and not the other. I can use the next() function to traverse but it throws StopIteration when the generator is exhausted, how do I know which one is exhausted?

```
try:
    A = next(tableAEnum)
    B = next(tableBEnum)
    flag =  True
    i = 0
    while flag:       
        if A.on[i] < B.on[i]:
            A = next(tableAEnum)
        elif A.on[i] < B.on[i]:
            B = next(tableBEnum)
        else:
            A = next(tableAEnum)
            B = next(tableBEnum)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Here I would like to know if tableBEnum got exhausted I would like add everything from that point to another dataframe and return.

Comment: It is not possible to do this, in general, without reading all the elements first. Here is a simple proof: suppose that one of the generators will produce `1`, followed by `0` a million times; the other will produce `2` a million times, followed by `1`. When we see the `1` from the first generator, we can't know that there is also a `1` present in the second generator, until we find it; and we can't find it until we read every element (because we need to find the last element, and we have to read the other elements in order to see what the last value is).

Comment: Unless you have some other guarantee on the data, e.g. the generators will output values in a sorted order, then the generators cannot help you save memory, and it would be better to just use lists/tuples/etc. in the first place.

Comment: Yes, they will be sorted. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: It would help to show some code, in order to understand the algorithm you are using, and where the problem occurs. Please read [mre]. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: the one that is exhausted is the one you called `next()` on when the `StopIteration` was raised

Comment: Are you actually using SQL to get the generators? Why not get the difference using SQL query itself?

Comment: I am trying to get difference 2 different tables from 2 different databases.